# Mysql join query on same table

Tags: php, mysql, cakephp

I have table like

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `categories` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `title` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `parent_id` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `status` enum('1','2') NOT NULL COMMENT '''1''=active,''2''=inactive',
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
)
```

now here I want records like

id,title,parent_title,status

means I want relative title in place of parent_id(at here parent_title)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$fields = array('c1.id, c1.title, c2.title as parent_title, c1.status');
        $joins = array();
            $joins[] = array(
                'table' => 'categories',
                'foreignKey' => false,
                'conditions' => 'c2.id = c1.parent_id',
                'type' => 'LEFT',
                'alias' => 'c2',
            );

$this->paginate = compact('fields', 'joins');
```

Answer (score 2):

Here it is mate:

```
SELECT c1.id, c1.title, c2.title as parent_title, c1.status
FROM categories c1
LEFT JOIN categories c2 ON (c2.id = c1.parent_id)
```

Comment: have you any idea how to do same things in cakephp?

Comment: Hey mate, sorry I don't work with cake. However you should be able to join the same entity in your Entity Manager. =)

Answer (score 1):

### Cakephp code

**In Category Controller**

```
$fields=array(
            'Category.*',
            'ParentCategory.title'
            );
$data = $this->Category->find("all",array(
                'fields' => $fields,
                'recursive'=>0
            ));
```

**In category Model**

```
var $belongsTo = array(

        'ParentCategory' => array(
            'className' => 'Category',
            'foreignKey' => 'parent_id',
            'conditions' => '',
            'fields' => '',
            'order' => ''
        )
);
```

Comment: in this case I need to create one more model 'ParentCategory'?

Comment: also I need to include this model in my controller ?